# VerifiedFunctor - prove map (map g) x = x

Tags: functor, proof, idris, theorem-proving

I'm trying to prove a statement about `VerifiedFunctor` interface (a `Functor` which `map` method respects identity and composition):

```
interface Functor f => VerifiedFunctor (f : Type -> Type) where
    functorIdentity : {a : Type} -> (g : a -> a) -> ((v : a) -> g v = v) ->
                      (x : f a) -> map g x = x
```

Here's the statement (which logically says that `map . map` for two given functors also respects identity):

```
functorIdentityCompose : (VerifiedFunctor f1, VerifiedFunctor f2) =>
                         (g : a -> a) -> ((v : a) -> g v = v) ->
                         (x : f2 (f1 a)) -> map (map g) x = x
functorIdentityCompose fnId prId = functorIdentity (map fnId) (functorIdentity fnId prId)
```

However, I'm getting following error:

```
Type mismatch between
        (x : f1 a) -> map fnId x = x (Type of functorIdentity fnId prId)
and
        (v : f a) -> map fnId v = v (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                f1 a
        and
                f a
```

I tried to specify all implicit arguments:

```
functorIdentityCompose : (VerifiedFunctor f1, VerifiedFunctor f2) =>
                         {a : Type} -> {f1 : Type -> Type} -> {f2 : Type -> Type} ->
                         (g : a -> a) -> ((v : a) -> g v = v) -> (x : f2 (f1 a)) ->
                         map {f=f2} {a=f1 a} {b=f1 a} (map {f=f1} {a=a} {b=a} g) x = x
```

... But got another error:

```
When checking argument func to function Prelude.Functor.map:
        Can't find implementation for Functor f15
```

So any ideas what is wrong here and how to prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a heuristic: when "obvious" things don't work... eta-expand! So this works:

```
functorIdentityCompose : (VerifiedFunctor f1, VerifiedFunctor f2) =>
  (g : a -> a) -> ((v : a) -> g v = v) ->
  (x : f2 (f1 a)) -> map (map g) x = x
functorIdentityCompose fnId prId x =
  functorIdentity (map fnId) (\y => functorIdentity fnId prId y) x
```

It looks like full application triggers instance search.